# How to compare two tables data and show only matched data in drop down list

Tags: asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I have two tables student and teacher and i want to compare their school branches and show only matched student in drop down using linq

Below is the code,

```
var teacher = db.TeacherEnroll.Select(x =>new{x.BranchClassesId,x.SubjectId});           
var student = db.EnrollInClass.Select(x => new { x.ClassSubject.ClassesId, x.BranchClassesId });          
ViewBag.show = db.EnrollInClass.ToList().Where(x=>student.Equals(teacher));               
return View();
```

Answer (score 1):

query below should give the students that has common branches with teachers

```
var students = 
(from t in db.TeacherEnroll
from s in db.EnrollInClass.Where(s => s.BranchClassedId == t.BranchClassesId)
select s).ToList();
```